# Storing large objects for a user session in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making use of Google API client gem which returns data and is then wrapped in the an object. I want to use this data between sessions. How should I store it? I thought at first I could serialize it then put it into a table, but ran into problems with the type of object it is an gave up. Actually thereafter I thought it would be neater to take the data I need and put it into an array of hashes (eg. for youtube videos - title, id, thumbnail etc) so I extracted what I needed and done so. Now, I have an array - should I store it in the database for the user or should I put it into a session var? Session var seems easier, no need to create an additional table etc but does that mean it will be stored as a cookie? Might be a rather large cookie then. Anyway advise here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you not store in Redis or a similar semi-persistent data store?

Comment: Have you solved the issue? If so, can you please share the knowledge with us? Did you try the suggested answer?

Comment: No I scrapped the idea, I was spending too much time on it. I opted instead to extract the fields I required and put them into their own columns. Having done some tests of `serialize` I found it handled simple objects well but didn't seem to like the object I was using.

Answer (score 0):

First, with database storage: with ActiveRecord you can simply store JSON. So, if your object can be serialized correctly, than there are no problems to store it in DB. just add this line to your model:

```
serialize :data, JSON.
```

Though, I think you can perfectly use session var for that purpose. By default, yes, it will be stored as a cookie - but if you think it's too much information, you can configure rails to use server-side storage instead.